# How to fix bone rotation also causing translation?

Tags: bones

I have a model that uses the Mixamo rig, but I added a jaw bone to control the lower jaw. The bone is parented to the neck bone with an offset.

[image]

Everything is fine until I rotate the jaw bone, in which case the jaw appears to translate as well as rotate, though the rotation doesn't act as I would expect either.

[image]

I've tried everything I can think of and searched the web for help, to no avail. I've not encountered this issue before, and I'm sure it's something I'm overlooking, and any help would be very much appreciated.

I won't use blender-exchange for any model, thank you, as I want to retain my ownership rights of my files.

Comment: Can you provide a download to your file?
It could be that the jaw is also partially parented to another bone, that the bone is not rotating in it's own local axis, that the bone is not in the same default position when it's posed or other things. But whatever it is, it's gonna be pretty hard to tell without actually looking at the file

Comment: You can upload your file to blender-exchange: 
https://blend-exchange.com/ 
You should edit the question to have a link to it for other people to see clearly

Comment: I added a link to the file in the original message.

Comment: So I found that by making the bone much bigger and setting it back a ways the animation looks better, but I don't think this should need to be done, as the animation should hinge properly on the bone. I retarted with the original Mixamo file and added a new bone and it did the same thing.

Comment: The link doesn't seem to work. Use blender-exchange, it's for this kind of thing